# Upgrading Angular version

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, requirejs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a web application using angular v1.1.5 and i am trying to update this to v.1.2.9.

I have downloaded v1.2.9 and the corresponding route.js file however when trying to run my application, i am seeing the below:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.9%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngRoute%26p1
```

**main.js:**

```
(function(require) {
'use strict';

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/resources/js',
    paths: {
        'zepto'     : 'vendor/zepto',
        'jquery'    : 'vendor/jquery',
        'angular'   : 'vendor/angular',         
        'ngRoute'   : 'vendor/route',
        // 'ngResource': 'vendor/resource',
        'router'    : 'vendor/page',
        'history'   : 'vendor/history.iegte8',
        'event'     : 'vendor/eventemitter2'
    },
    shim: {
        'zepto'     : { exports: '$' },         
        'angular'   : { deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'angular' },
        'ngRoute'   : { deps: ['angular'], exports: 'angular' },
        // 'ngResource': { deps: ['angular'], exports: 'angular' },
        'app'       : { deps: ['angular'] },
        'router'    : { exports: 'page'}            
    }
});

require(['angular', 'app'], function (angular, app) {
    angular.bootstrap(document,['app']);
});

})(this.require);
```

**app.js:**

```
define("app", ["angular"], function(angular){

var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "home.html",
            controller: "HomeController"
        })
        .when("/products", {
            templateUrl: "products.html",
            controller: "ProductsController"
        })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/products'});
});

return app;
});
```

Any advice appreciated.

**Update************************************************

If i change (app.js):

```
define("app", ["angular"], function(angular){
```

to:

```
define("app", ["angular", "ngRoute"], function(angular){
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: e is undefined   

...controller,f),b.controllerAs&&(a[b.controllerAs]=f),c.data("$ngControllerControl...
```

Comment: Did you add the script reference to angular-route.min.js as well?

Comment: @PhilSandler - sorry, could you explain what you mean by that? I added 'ngRoute'   : 'vendor/route', to my require.config section

Comment: A common problem I see people have when upgrading is that routing is now is a separate .js file, which needs to be referenced in a script tag.  Maybe require takes care of this for you (I'm not that familiar with it).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with require.js, but wouldn't you need to inject it here as well?

```
require(['angular', 'ngRoute', 'app'], function (angular, app, ngRoute) {
    angular.bootstrap(document,['app', 'ngRoute']);
});
```

I might be out on deep waters here though.

Comment: added your suggestion, and my thought on the update above.. Seeing this error: TypeError: e is undefined
 

...controller,f),b.controllerAs&&(a[b.controllerAs]=f),c.data("$ngControllerControl...